# JavaScript: The function listener called by this event listener is not as expected

Tags: javascript

Although it is somewhat simplistic, when you execute the following code, this points to the document and you can not get an instance of Hoge.

If you make variables and functions global, there is no meaning defined in the closure, and is there any better way?

```
var Hoge = function() {
    this.hogehoge = 'hogehoge';
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.change, false);
};

Hoge.prototype = {
    change: function(e) {
        e.pageX
        console.log(this.hogehoge); // undefined
    }
};

let hoge = new Hoge();
```

I expect the output of `console.log` to be `'hogehoge'`, but the actual output is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `this.change` in outer context, you need to bind this like `this.change.bind(this)` to make `this` context remain the same as you have while clicking.

```js
var Hoge = function() {
    this.hogehoge = 'hogehoge';
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.change.bind(this), false);
};

Hoge.prototype = {
    change: function(e) {
        e.pageX;
        console.log(this.hogehoge); // undefined
    }
};

let hoge = new Hoge();
```

> For more information, Read how `this` gets its context here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this